# ssas total calculation incorrect when using IIF in calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, bids

I cannot understand why Total of calculated member is displayed incorrect. How should I change calculated member for it to work correctly?

Calculated Member:

```
 CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].AverageScore
    AS IIF([Measures].[Distance]<2001,0,[Measures].[avgscore]/[Measures].[Date Count]),
 VISIBLE = 1;
```

[image]

It seems that Total is calculated without checking value in "AverageScore" for that month.

thanks

Comment: What should be the correct value for total average?

Comment: it should be (74+0)/2 = 37.

Comment: Check the avgscore by date values. SSAS doesn't calculate it as (74+0)/2 it actually aggregates (calculates average) every date and divide by the total of dates.

Comment: I understand that. Please note how I created AverageScore calculated member. I did sort of filter on [Measures].[Distance], so that when Distance < 2001 AverageScore is 0. Else it is calculated normally. If i would remove this IIF statement, calculation would be correct and result would be as it is now for Total AverageScore - 69. Problem is that after I add IIF this is not changing and still calculating like there were no IIF

Comment: Try validating avgscore. Are there cases when Distance >= 2001 and avgscore = 0?

Comment: there cannot be such cases. When Distance >=2000 avgscore is always > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If avgscore is a hidden measure you don't want visible and if it's a physical measure not a calculated measure try adding this before your current calc:

```
Scope([Driver Dim].[Driver].[Driver].Members, [Date].[Month].[Month].Members);
  [Measures].[avgscore] = iif([Measures].[Distance]<2001,Null,[Measures].[avgscore]);
End scope;
```

That should zero out avgscore for low distance driver months so that the grand total will work right. If that won't work then explain avgscore further.

How many rows per driver per month are there? I assume more than one otherwise I would tell you to do the <2001 check in SQL.